# Can a thread acquire another sychronized block if it already has a lock of synchronized block

Tags: java, multithreading

So my question is if my thread A has acquired access to a synchronized method S1() can it acquire access to another synchronized method S2() or a normal method.

Comment: Totally depends on the kind of _synchonization utility_ used. With some you can use an idempotent lock, while others doesn't support this.

Comment: Maybe make the title more like the question, less confusing. Is the critical point whether your thread can call another method without waiting?

Comment: Why not just try it?

Answer (score 2):

**Short Answer**: Yes (or No, depending how you read the question)

In Java, a thread can keep calling synchronized methods on an object instance as long as the thread holds the instance's monitor.

So if you have an instance of Class Blah, defined as follows...

```
class Blah {
  private int value = 0;

  synchronized void foo() {
      value += 1;
  }
  synchronized void foo2TheMax(int max) {
      if (value > max) {
          value = 0;
      }
      foo(); // This does not wait. Thread already has the monitor.
  }

}
```

When a thread calls foo2TheMAx(n) it may wait to obtain the instance's monitor.

But it will not wait again when foo2TheMax() calls foo().

Once the thread has the monitor it can keep calling synchronized methods without waiting until it releases the monitor.

So if you call foo() twice as Class Meh's do2Foos() method does...

```
class Meh {

void do2Foos(Blah blah) {
    blah.foo(); // May wait for blah's monitor.
    blah.foo(); // Also may wait for blah's monitor.
}
```

}

Then you may wait twice, because the monitor is released when returning from foo().

Note: Each synchronized block or method does not have its own lock. The synchronized keyword represents a single mutual exclusion constraint covering all synchronized methods and blocks for an object instance.

Comment: This has a lot to do with the fact that adding `synchronized` directly onto a method of a class is just a syntactic sugar for `void foo() { synchronized(this) { [... method body ...] } }`.

Comment: @Andy Sure, the synchronized block is another way to use the same monitor mechanism. And it can help illustrate what's happening.

Comment: Actually, this is all possible because intrinsic lock of each `Object` is reentrant.

Answer (score 1):

Java uses concept of re-entrant lock, once your thread gets a lock on object, it need not wait for the lock again, and can execute the synchronized method within a synchronized method.

Hope it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

If your methods `S1` and `S2` are part of the same object instance, then they both use the same lock, and Java is clever enough to "just work". You'll be able to call `S2` from within `S1`, it will realise you already have the lock, and it won't block again or deadlock. It will release it after `S1` exits.

---

If `S1` and `S2` belong to different classes, or to different instances of the same class, things get a little more complicated as they are different locks. There's nothing to stop that working, so while you hold the lock for `S1` you're allowed to wait for and acquire the lock for `S2`, and that works.

But you can get into deadlocks if another thread already holds the lock for the object which has the `S2` method, and is trying to acquire the lock for the object which has the `S1` method. There might be a situation where both threads hold one of the locks and are waiting for the other, and that might be a race condition which only occurs rarely. Once in that situation, there's very little that your code can do to recover from it. It's hard to predict with real-life code but it can be minimised by:

- Reducing the number of separate locks in your system
- Where appropriate (not where it would break your thread safety), releasing the first lock before acquiring the second
- Always acquiring locks in the same order in every thread
- Using some of the `java.util.concurrent` utilities where appropriate instead of locking

---

- I'm assuming you're using the `synchronized` keyword rather than any of the utilities in the `java.util.concurrent` package.
- I'm also assuming the call to `S2` happens from within the `S1` method.